# multiple middleware to Laravel 5 route not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

i want to view dashboard when logged in as both "admin" and "jeweller".
When i log in a "admin" its redirecting to dashboard, when when i log in as jeweller, its not going to dashboard.
I have 2 types of admin & tables ie.. "admin", "jeweller"

In auth.php , i have created 2 types of providers

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'jeweler' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'jewelers',
        ],
    ],
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'jewelers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Jeweler::class,
        ],
    ],
```

i have declared a middleware called "AdminAuthenticated" , in AdminAuthenticated.php we have

```
class AdminAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

and in web.php we have

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware'=>
  ['adminAuth:admin','adminAuth:jeweler']], function () {
});
```

and in kernal we have

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticated::class,
    ];
```

Comment: You can add a middleware group in your `$middlewareGroups` array e.g. `'admin' =>['adminAuth:admin','adminAuth:jeweler']` and set your group middleware to `admin`

Comment: You should take a look at `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware and compare your own `AdminAuthenticated` middleware if they are both doing the same logic for authenticating.

Comment: @apokryfos ..  
i tried this, but result is same, cant login with jeweler

Comment: If you need one of the two middleware to pass then you should combine them into a `AuthWithAdminOrJewler` middleware. Laravel doesn't "or" the middleware, all must pass.

Comment: @apokryfos.. thanks that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to check one of the guards:

```
class AdminAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (func_num_args() == 2 && \Auth::check()) { //Default guard
             return $next($request);     
        }  
        for ($i = 2; $i < func_num_args();$i++) {
             if (Auth::guard(func_get_arg($i))->check()) {
                 return $next($request);
             }
        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

This middleware will pass if one of the specified guards passes or if the default guard passes when there's no parameters.

You can use it like:

```
Route::group([ 
      'prefix' => 'admin',
      'middleware' => 'adminAuth:admin,jewler' 
    ], function () { ...
```

Comment: if ($guards) { $guards = explode('-', $guards); foreach ($guards as $guard) { if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { return $next($request); } } } return redirect()->route('admin.login'); and root to ,'middleware'=>['adminAuth:jeweler-admin']

Comment: That would also work but if you comma-separate them then they'll be passed as separate parameters to the middleware instead of a single parameter and will be in the func_get_args() array

Answer (score 3):

```
class AdminAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if ($guards) {

            foreach ($guards as $guard) {
                if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
                }
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

use

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware'=>
  ['adminAuth:admin,jeweler']], function () {
});
```

Comment: i tried this, but result is same, cant login with jeweler

Comment: modified your answer to ...... if ($guards) {
            $guards = explode('-', $guards);
            foreach ($guards as $guard) {
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }


        }
        return redirect()->route('admin.login'); and root to ,'middleware'=>['adminAuth:jeweler-admin']

Comment: This middleware will fail if the user isn't authenticated on all the supplied guards. I thought the problem was that OP wanted the user to be authenticated on at least one guard.